# share photo with standard text - Facebook iOS SDK 4.x

Tags: ios, facebook, image, swift, sdk

I need to post a picture on the user's wall with a standard text. Can you do this with the FBSDK 4.x?

```
    let photoshare = FBSDKSharePhoto(image: recortarImagem(), userGenerated: true) 
    let content = FBSDKSharePhotoContent()
    content.photos = [photoshare]

    let dialog = FBSDKShareDialog()
    dialog.delegate = self
    dialog.shareContent = content
    dialog.fromViewController = self
    dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogMode.ShareSheet

    dialog.show()
```

Comment: You are not allowed to pre-fill the image caption – it has to be typed in by the user.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, this would violate the Platform Policy of Facebook (see 2.3, pre-filling at https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#control).

This being said, `FBSDKSharePhoto` has a field, `caption` that you can put a **user-generated message** in.